# Merge 2 sets of Object + Array Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to merge 2 sets of Object & Array like below

```
{
  exclude: ['placeholder'],
  attributes: { MYID : '' }
  map: 'input'
}
```

AND

```
{
 exclude: ['options'],
 attributes: { class: '', id:'', name:'', },
 map: '',
}
```

I tried using jQuery's `$.extend` function it worked but it only merge objects.
And also tried with lodash js which also dose not work.
I get output as

```
{
  exclude: ['options'],
  attributes: { class: '', id: '', name: '', MYID: '' },
  map: '',
}
```

I need output like

```
{
  exclude: ['options','placeholder'],
  attributes: { class: '', id: '', name: '', MYID: '' },
  map: '',
}
```

Code I tried using

```
$.extend(true,{
  exclude: ['placeholder'],
  attributes: { MYID : '' }
  map: 'input'
},{
 exclude: ['options'],
 attributes: { class: '', id:'', name:'', },
 map: '',
});
```

Comment: Please add the code you've already tried.

Comment: @Andy done . please check.

Comment: Use concat() to concatenate the "exclude" array,  for-in loop to remap the "attributes", and "map" is always an empty string, so just keep it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create custom function for this using `for...in` loop and check type of each value.

```js
var obj1 = {
  exclude: ['placeholder'],
  attributes: { MYID : '' },
  map: 'input'
}

var obj2 = {
 exclude: ['options'],
 attributes: { class: '', id:'', name:'', },
 map: '',
}


function merge(o1, o2) {
  for (var i in o2) {
    if (o1[i]) {
      if (typeof o2[i] == 'object') {
        if (Array.isArray(o2[i])) o1[i].push(...o2[i])
        else o1[i] = Object.assign({}, o1[i], o2[i])
      } else {
        o1[i] = o2[i]
      }
    } else {
      o1[i] = o2[i]
    }
  }
  return o1;
}


console.log(merge(obj1, obj2))
```

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for your answer. can i know why the function is not returning any values ? is it changing the original variable ?

Comment: @Varun Sridharan Yes it's modifying first object

Comment: thanks. but i need the function to return the value.

Comment: You can just return first object then.

Comment: @Varun Sridharan Yes as i said it will modify first object.

Comment: Ok thanks. will check . sorry for asking more things. i am new to js :)

Comment: Varun Sridharan No problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152058/discussion-between-varun-sridharan-and-nenad-vracar).

Answer (score 1):

Because `_.extend(...)` overrides existing fields instead of fill it.

Try using [_.mergeWith(,, customizer)](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#mergeWith) with customizer function, that is responsible for merging fields the way is needed, like:

```
function customizer(initialObject, source) {
    if (_.isArray(initialObject)) {
        return initialObject.concat(source);
    } else if (_.isObject(initialObject)) {
        return _.extend(initialObject, source);
    } else {
        return source;
    }
}

_.mergeWith({a: [1], b: {c: 4}}, {a: [2, 3], b: {d: 5}}, customizer);

//{a: Array(3), b: {…}}
//a
//:
//(3) [1, 2, 3]
//b
//:
//{c: 4, d: 5}
//__proto__
//:
//Object
```

Comment: OP is using jQuery, not lodash

Comment: He said he used lodash as well